# Amazon SES getSendStatistics

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am facing some problem related to getSendStatistics in Amazon SES Api, problem is that when i call getSendStatistics first time return data is not same as Second time call getSendStatistics (when page is refresh).

Example

First time return data

```
[GetSendStatisticsResult] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                    [SendDataPoints] => CFSimpleXML Object
                        (
                            [member] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => CFSimpleXML Object
                                        (
                                            [DeliveryAttempts] => 3
                                            [Timestamp] => 2013-04-23T04:47:00Z
                                            [Rejects] => 0
                                            [Bounces] => 0
                                            [Complaints] => 0
                                        )

                                    [1] => CFSimpleXML Object
                                        (
                                            [DeliveryAttempts] => 1
                                            [Timestamp] => 2013-04-23T10:17:00Z
                                            [Rejects] => 0
                                            [Bounces] => 0
                                            [Complaints] => 0
                                        )
                                  )
                               )
                              )
```

Second time return data

```
[GetSendStatisticsResult] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                    [SendDataPoints] => CFSimpleXML Object
                        (
                            [member] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => CFSimpleXML Object
                                        (
                                            [DeliveryAttempts] => 1
                                            [Timestamp] => 2013-04-23T10:17:00Z
                                            [Rejects] => 0
                                            [Bounces] => 0
                                            [Complaints] => 0
                                        )

                                    [1] => CFSimpleXML Object
                                        (
                                           [DeliveryAttempts] => 3
                                            [Timestamp] => 2013-04-23T04:47:00Z
                                            [Rejects] => 0
                                            [Bounces] => 0
                                            [Complaints] => 0
                                        )
                                  )
                               )
                              )
```

some how its change it position don't know what happening can any one guide me about this problem . i am newbie for Amazon SES

Thank You

Comment: Can u please provide the javascript SDK link for "GetSendStatistics". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to AWS, there is no guarantee, at any particular moment, that statistics are 100% up to date - there may be a reporting lag, even if you haven't sent something in between the calls.

> We may delay the data returned in GetSendStatistics in order to better aggregate the data, and it is not guaranteed to be accurate to the minute.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=278174

Could this possibly explain what you are seeing?

Comment: its mean i hit this 'GetSendStatistics' after some time, let say page refresh 5-10 min difference

Comment: I also know about there ordering actually when my recent sending mail static are in middle of data record it should be at top or lower of the record so what is the reason behind it?